# Warning message while using "if" condition in sapply()

Tags: r, sapply

```
v5<-sapply(v4, function(x) {if(x>0) levels[2] else levels[1]})
  return(v5)
```

Shows the following warning message:

```
In if (x > 0) 1 else -1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

`sapply` takes `x` as a single element of the vector `v4` but still error pops up when I try to run this code.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. What are `v4` and `levels`? Does `sapply(v4, function(x) ifelse(x>0,levels[2],levels[1]))` work for you?

Comment: Share a reproducible example.

Comment: The problem is exactly as the warning message indicates. The condition supplied to `if` must evaluate to a _single_ TRUE or FALSE. In your case `x` has more than one element so `x > 0)` returns a logical vector of length greater than one.